# Laravel Update multiple records with two input data

Tags: arrays, laravel-5

Am building an e-commerce app where I want to update two records in my database with a couple of input fields from my HTML or blade template.
I have a product with its sizes as an option for the product. So a shirt can have small as option 1, medium as option 2, and large as option 3. I have then created a `productProductOptions` table with `product_id` column and `product_option_id` column.

If the admin wants to update a product, I loop through the `productProductOptions` table and present the product's options to the product/edit page. So once the necessary options are changed then I can grab them back into the `productProductOptions` again.

The DB:

```
   product_id | product_option_id
        1     |         2
        1     |         3
```

This is my HTML :

```html
@foreach($productOptions as $thisProduct)
   <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('option_id') ? 'has-error': '' }}">
            <label for="size">Sizes:</label>   
             
            <select class="form-control" id="size" class="form-control" name="option_id[]">

            @if(isset($thisProduct))    

               @foreach($options as $option)

                 <option value="{{ $option->id }}" @if($thisProduct->productOption->id == $option->id) selected="selected" @endif>{{ $option->name }}</option>

               @endforeach
                   
            @endif

         <select/>
      </div>
   </div>
@endforeach
```

### This is my controller:

```php
$productProductOptions = ProductProductOption::where('product_id', $product->id)->get();

for ($i=0; $i < count($request->option_id); $i++) { 

   foreach ($productProductOptions as $productProductOption) {

        $productProductOption->update(['product_option_id' => $request->option_id[$i]]);

   }

}
```

But it picks up the last option from the form and updates both records with it.
For example, The admin picks small = option `1` and medium = option `2`, both records get updated with `2`.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $productProductOption = []; $i = 0;

    foreach ($request->option_id as $optionId) {

        $productProductOption[$optionId] = [ 
            'regular_price'     => $request->regular_price[$i], 
            'sales_price'       => $request->sales_price[$i],  
            'quantity_available'=> $request->quantity_available[$i] 

        ];

        $i+=1;

    }

    $product->options()->sync($productProductOption);
```